# How to show the previously selected values(dynamic) on a dropdown after oneditsave in Node-Red?

Tags: node.js, node-red

I'm having a custom node which includes two dropdowns which are independent to each other.

So the second dropdown values changes, according to the selected value from the first drop down.

What I've tried now is:

- User drags my custom node (iotinput) choses values from both the drop
  downs and clicks the Done.
- He drags another custom node (iotinput) again, and select different
  values and clicks Done.
- So there're two custom nodes at the moment.
- So when the user goes back and click in either one of those nodes, it
  should show the previously selected values which I'm unable to do at
  the moment.
- So how much custom nodes he's dragging into the flow, the user should
  be able to see the previously selected values after clicking Done.

**NOTE**: All the above I'm doing it without deploying the flow.

The problem I'm facing here is, since I'm loading my dropdowns from an ajax call, I'm unable to load the previously selected values.

I've checked the in-built nodes in Node-Red which has dropdowns, where the options values are hard coded. I was able to do it for a textbox successfully.

But then I'm clueless, how could I do it for dropdowns which are getting created dynamically? Is there anyway in Node-Red to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In a node's `oneditprepare` function you have access to its current configuration. This means that once you've dynamically added to the contents to the `select` boxes, you can set the selected value based on the node property.

For example, if a node has a property `colour`, you can do:

```
oneditprepare: function() {
    var node = this;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.com/colours.json'
        success: function(result) {
            // ... do whatever you need to build you select box
            // then set the current value:
            $('#mySelectBox').val(node.colour);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks @knolleary. But how am I to restore the values for the dropdowns for the particular node id, when the user double clicks it again? Is it possible to store the dropdown values somewhere for the specific node id so that I can load them back if the node-id matches, if not if I just create a variable for the node-id and check for the value when the user double clicks for the second time, the variable would get replaced with the node-id if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: I guess you could add something to the global scope (eg `window.myValueCache`) to store the retrieved data keyed by `id`) - it would only be stored within the current editor session, so your code will have to handle retrieving it from whatever remote source you have regardless.

Comment: You mean something like `localStorage`, in order to store the values within the browser session?

Comment: You could use localStorage, but I wouldn't. Just use global variable of your own choosing declared outside of the scope of your oneditprepare function.

Comment: Thank you @knolleary, I'll go with that!