# Node RED custom node, populate dynamic values in dropdown. Show selected value on opening node. Support for same type of multiple nodes

Tags: drop-down-menu, node-red

Node red custom node, 1 drop-down field shows values dynamically from a database.
User can select any value & save the node.
When user reopens same node, drop-down should show the previously selected value.
It works in one node only.
But if we put multiple nodes of same type it shows same value in all nodes.

The reason is to store the selected value global variable is used outside oneditprepare function.
When user wants to use many same types of nodes then the global variable shows same value in different nodes because of the global variable.

How to solve this issue?

I looked at [How to show the previously selected values(dynamic) on a dropdown after oneditsave in Node-Red?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42849765/how-to-show-the-previously-selected-valuesdynamic-on-a-dropdown-after-oneditsa) as well.

The other way, I think to solve this issue is below.
Node shows value in side bar info. We can get value from that and assign it to dropdown. But the problem in that case is we have to write code in oneditprepare to assign value to dropdown.

And Side bar property gets value after complete execution of oneditprepare.

Thanks.

**Code for above description:**

```
<div class="form-row">
      <label for="node-input-toolId"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> Tool Id</label>
      <select id="node-input-toolId" style="width:125px !important" required>
                <option value=""></option>
      </select>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
var globalToolId;


defaults:{
    toolId: {value:"", required:true} // along with some other fields
}
```

oneditprepare:

```
// ajax call to database to fetch values
$.ajax({
    url: solrUrl,
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data) {
        for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++) // Assume list has all values fetched from db
        {
            var dbVal = list[i];
            var newOption = $('<option value="'+dbVal+'">'+dbVal+'</option>'); // Add all values to the dropdown list
            $("#node-input-toolId").append(newOption);
        }

        // This will show default toolId selected previously
        if(globalToolId != null && globalToolId != '')
        {
            $("#node-input-toolId").val(globalToolId);
        }
    }
});

// On change of toolId2, save selected Tool Id in global variable.
$('#node-input-toolId2').change(function(e){
    globalToolId = $('#node-input-toolId').val();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to solve this would be to define a [regular node property](https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/properties) to store the selection in. That way each node can have its own selected value.

Yes that means you need to have some code in `oneditprepare` in order to set the selected value from the dynamically generated list - but that's just how its done; it is not a 'problem'. Besides, if you're doing it with a global variable, you must have some code to do the same task.

Comment: I can populate dynamic value in one node. For multiple nodes, it's taking same value for all nodes which is incorrect because of the use of global variable. I am using node property as well.

Comment: Without seeing specific code, I'm not sure what else to say. If you are using a node property then each node will have its own value. If you are using a single global, then all nodes will have that global value. Why use a global if it's the cause of the issue you are asking about?

Comment: I added the code. Code will populate dynamic values from DB after saving it in a node. But this works with the use of global variable, 1 value will be referred to all same type of nodes. How to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Without using global variable how can I populate dynamic value to dropdown?
Is there any other way I can fetch previously selected value? Please refer to the code. 
Thanks.

Comment: I simply don't understand why you aren't storing this as a node-instance property. This isn't a great place for this sort of discussion. Can I suggest you post to the Node-RED Forum (link at nodered.org) so it can be properly discussed?